# Trigonometric and hyperbolic functions for complex number in c++

Tags: c++

iam working on my own class for complex numbers which add,subtract,multiply,divide 2 complex numbers and besides this behavior it also get Trigonometric and hyperbolic functions for complex numbers
can you help me please in implementing this Trigonometric and hyperbolic functions

and this is my behaviors including sine function is this implementation is true ??

void complex::get(){

```
cout<<"Real part is:"<<real<<"\n"<<"Imaginary part is:"<<imag<<"\n";
```

}
void complex::add(complex &sum ,const complex &num1,const complex &num2 )
{

```
sum.real=num1.real+num2.real;
sum.imag=num1.imag+num2.imag;
```

}

void complex::sub (complex &subt,const complex &num1,const complex &num2 )
{

```
subt.real=num1.real-num2.real;

subt.imag=num1.imag-num2.imag;
```

}

void complex::multi (complex &product,const complex &num1,const complex &num2)

{

```
product.real=(num1.real*num2.real)-(num1.imag*num2.imag);

product.imag=(num1.real*num2.imag)+(num1.imag*num2.real);
```

}

void complex::div (complex &divis,const complex &num1,const complex &num2)

{

divis.real=((num1.real*num2.real)+(num1.imag*num2.imag))/((num2.real*num2.real)+(num2.imag*num2.imag));

divis.imag=((num1.imag*num2.real)-(num1.real*num2.imag))/((num2.real*num2.real)+(num2.imag*num2.imag));

}

complex complex::_sin(void)

{
    complex a;
    complex temp;
    temp.real=sin(a.real)*cosh(a.imag);
    temp.imag=cos(a.real)*sinh(a.imag);

```
return temp;
```

}

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Naturally, you've looked at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/math/doc/html/index.html and found it doesn't meet your requirements, right?

Comment: @pontus: perhaps  this is sufficient: http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/. No need for Boost.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://jwbales.us/precal/part6/part6.3.html) talks about how you can easily define trig functions with the real and complex parts of your number.

[This page](http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/Hyperbolic_Functions.htm) starts with sinh and cosh (defined in terms of *e* so you can use the `exp` function for that) which allows you to define the other hyperbolic functions.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like homework, but in this case the Standard Library has already done the work for you in the [`<complex>` header](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/).

If you really want to reimplement them, see Jacob's answer, which will have the small gorey details.

Answer (score 0):

Since the trigonometric and hyperbolic functions are defined in terms of complex exponentiation, start by implementing Euler's identity (which produces a complex result using only real trigonometric functions).